# Subscribing to Events in C#.NET MVC pattern

Tags: c#, events, model-view-controller, event-handling, devexpress

I am using `DevExpress` Dashboard `MVC Control` with my Project.

I need to subscribe to some of the events supported by the control from server side.Currently I'm subscribing to them in the `MVC Controller`.

Is this the best place where I should place `Event Handling` code? Do these events need to be unsubscribed to avoid memory leaks?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string mode)
    {
        //Some code commented
        DashboardConfigurator.Default.CustomFilterExpression += MvcDashboard_CustomFilterExpression;          
        DashboardConfigurator.Default.CustomParameters += (sender, eventArgs) =>{
        //Event specific code
        }; 

            return View();
        }

   public void MvcDashboard_CustomFilterExpression(object sender, CustomFilterExpressionWebEventArgs e)
   {

       // Event specific code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress Suggests to define in Application_Start method in the Global.asax.cs

> We suggest specifying the default controller's settings in the Application_Start method in the Global.asax.cs file or in the RegisterService method in the DashboardConfig.cs file. The code snippet in the Step 9. Create a Dashboard Storage section of the Create an ASP.NET MVC Dashboard Application topic demonstrates this approach.